# Why it is calling String type argument method

Tags: java, string

Why does the compiler match the `String` overload, and not the `Object` overload?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method(null);
}

public static void method(Object o) {
    System.out.println("Object impl");
}

public static void method(String s) {
    System.out.println("String impl");
}
```

Comment: I think the JVM will always call the more specific matching signature when there are multiple matches.  `String` is more specific than `Object`, so it gets called.

Comment: OK. Try this: Object o = null; method(o); :D

Comment: Tim is right, the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) requires that the most specific method is called and `String` is more specific than `Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Compiler chooses the most specific method.String is a more specific type compared to the Object.

Answer (score 1):

> It is executing the string because it will find the near match of the null but 
>   if you try int and object as method parameter. then it will choose the object method to print.